# Render random combination of number of layers

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, render-layers

I’ve been looking hard for this and I haven’t really found a solution for my wishes. I’m not calling it a ‘problem’ because I feel like what I am trying to achieve could be fairly easy to one of the Wise Python guys out there.

My trust is in you guys..! So what I am trying to achieve is the following:

I have say, 100 different objects with a particle system animated. And I would like to render random combinations for these layers.

Preferably with a variable number of used layers for the combination. So there will be a total of say 100 different videos rendered all with a duration of 300 frames.

- Render 1 = 3 layers, layer 1,6,80
- Render 2 = 5 layers, layer 28,44,46,82,95
- Render 3 = 4 layers, layer 2,17,65
- Etc.

Now if the double random (layer ánd number of layers) is too advanced a simpler solution would work as well, whereas:

100 different videos will be rendered all with 3 random combinations of layers.

Is there any good documentation or example for what I am trying to accomplish? Can anyone help me in the right direction. I’m trying to learn. But an example would help me greatly!

I hope someone out there can lead the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, but it sounds pretty easy. Just need a way to hide and show layers in Python. However, objects and layers are not synonymous. In fact, hiding individual objects with Python might be much easier than swapping out layers.

Comment: Hi @TheLabCat thank you for your response. I might have used the word 'layers' to complicate my wishes. Hiding objects should work fine indeed. I can just have 100 objects in the scene and randomise activating them for the 100 renders to be made. 

So what I am looking for is a python script that will render my pre-made scene with 100 objects in a randomised maner. 
I want:
- to be able to set the number of renders to be made
- to be able to set the number of random layers to be used i.e. 3,4 or 5
- the script should randomly pick a few of the objects to show in the render

Any ideas?

Comment: random *objects to be used?

Comment: Were you able to reach that man ? How did you do that?
I'm looking for exactly the same script. If it creates a json file whit the "traits" it would be even better.

Comment: @GabrielMagalhães check out this. Might be helpful;
https://fruitzeus.gumroad.com/l/aWSEM

Worked for me! 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0vjuWopx5g&ab_channel=FruitZeus